# I want to add a flag column for records between two rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like the below . In this table I want to flag all rows between first purpose A (including first purpose A row)  and second purpose A for each Id with a flag.

| ID | Purpose | session |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1kks |
| 1 | B | 2ssk |
| 1 | B | 3pfk |
| 1 | A | 4lsk |
| 1 | B | 5kwk |
| 2 | A | 1kll |
| 2 | B | 2mlk |
| 2 | A | 4fnh |
| 2 | B | 5pts |

Expectation is as below . So All rows before the second purpose A is flagged for each distinct Id.

| ID | Purpose | session | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1kks | 1 |
| 1 | B | 2ssk | 1 |
| 1 | B | 3pfk | 1 |
| 1 | A | 4lsk | 0 |
| 1 | B | 5kwk | 0 |
| 2 | A | 1kll | 1 |
| 2 | B | 2mlk | 1 |
| 2 | A | 4fnh | 0 |
| 2 | B | 5pts | 0 |

Could let me know how we can achieve this,

Comment: How do you know which is the first A for any given id? Also please update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write on your own and explain what, specifically, you are stuck on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming the session if a order providing field for your data (as I see a 1, 2,3, 4,5), otherwise as NickW notes there is no actual order in your data.

We can start with a CTE to give us you start state:

```
with fake_data(id, purpose, session) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 'A', '1kks'),
        (1, 'B', '2ssk'),
        (1, 'B', '3pfk'),
        (1, 'A', '4lsk'),
        (1, 'B', '5kwk'),
        (2, 'A', '1kll'),
        (2, 'B', '2mlk'),
        (2, 'A', '4fnh'),
        (2, 'B', '5pts')
)
select *
from fake_data
order by 1,3;
```

So you want the from and including the first `A` until and not including the second/later `A`, thus we want to annotate the presence of A's, and then sum a value for each `A` seen, and flag/match the first batch.

Thus with a little more data, and that logic:

```
with fake_data(id, purpose, session) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 'A', '1kks'),
        (1, 'B', '2ssk'),
        (1, 'B', '3pfk'),
        (1, 'A', '4lsk'),
        (1, 'B', '5kwk'),
        (2, 'A', '1kll'),
        (2, 'B', '2mlk'),
        (2, 'A', '4fnh'),
        (2, 'B', '5pts'),
        (3, 'B', '1kll'),
        (3, 'A', '2mlk'),
        (3, 'B', '4fnh'),
        (3, 'A', '5pts')
)
select *
    ,purpose = 'A' as is_a
    ,sum(is_a::int) over (partition by id order by session) as sum_of_a
    ,sum_of_a = 1 as flag
from fake_data
order by 1,3;
```

[image]

Which can be all mashed together like:

```
select *
    ,sum((purpose = 'A')::int) over (partition by id order by session) = 1 as flag
from fake_data
order by 1,3;
```

[image]

So how this works is, first we check `purpose` is an `A` and then we [cast](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/cast) this BOOLEAN to a [INT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_decimal) which is the same as `IFF(is_a, 1, 0)`, ([IFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff) being the inline IF command) then we sum this chain of values using a window function form of [SUM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/sum), and then we check for the presence of the value 1, as we only want the first set, which as the enhanced data shows, works for ignore prefix data prior to the `A` also.